# How do I set the order Tab order control in visual studio for a form?

Tags: visual-studio

I would like to set the Tab order control in visual studio. How do I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Microsoft on their site have an example that may help you

```
<Grid>
  <Button Content="Button" TabIndex="0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="238,93,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75"/>
  <Button Content="Button" TabIndex="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="175,145,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75"/>
</Grid>
```

For more [information](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/1196b9fc-84dc-45fd-ac33-45abc7983f3b/tab-order-of-controls-in-wpf?forum=wpf)

Answer (score 1):

Goto View menu, click on **Tab Order**.

This activates the tab-order selection mode on the form. A number (representing the TabIndex property) appears in the upper-left corner of each control.

Click the controls sequentially to establish the tab order you want.

When you have finished, click Tab Order on the View menu again to leave tab order mode.

[image]